# WCF FaultException Without Sending StackTrace

Tags: wcf, stack-trace, soapfault, faultexception

I have some WCF services with predefined `FaultContract` attributes. When the `FaultException<TDetail>` exceptions are thrown, they're sending StackTrace, Source and other potentially unsave information.

Is it possible to return only:

- Detail (from the generic TDetail)
- FaultMessage
- FaultCode
- (and possibly) FaultReason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried rolling your own fault exception using [IErrorHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler?view=netframework-4.8)? Also make sure in your app config file, the [IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.description.servicedebugbehavior.includeexceptiondetailinfaults?view=netframework-4.8) attribute is set to false and,  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pedram/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices) might be helpful for best pratices.

Comment: IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults is already false. As I understand it, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults only applies to unhandled exceptions that are not already of type FaultException<TDetail>.

I already implemented an IErrorHandler in order to enforce a policy that all operations have a base FaultContract assigned and that automatically logs and rethrows unhandled exceptions in that base fault type.What I don't know is why WCF is passing more information than is defined in the FaultContract. I'm currently experiencing this behavior with wsHttpBinding and a SOAP client.

Comment: It turns out that there wasn't a problem with StackTrace being sent back to the client. (The problem was in front of the keyboard.) I was misinterpreting the response received from WCFStorm in the Response pane. The stacktrace and source were only information about the client and not the server. IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults definitely only applied to exceptions that are not "well known" though. Thanks for the help Terrance.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this @reifnir, you saved me from potentially a lot of wasted time trying to figure out how to prevent this!

Comment: Yeah, that's confusing, especially because even with IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=false, the stack trace says "Server stack trace: ..." although in reality it's the client stack trace only.